# How to solve "The IAM role configured on the integration or API Gateway doesn't have permissions to call the integration

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have a lambda function and an apigatewayv2. I am creating everything via terraform as below.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "prod_options" {
  description = "Production Lambda"
  environment {
    variables = var.prod_env

  }
  
  function_name                  = "prod-func"
  handler                        = "index.handler"
  layers                         = [
                                    aws_lambda_layer_version.node_modules_prod.arn
                                   ]
  memory_size                    = 1024
  package_type                   = "Zip"
  reserved_concurrent_executions = -1
  role                           = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn
  runtime                        = "nodejs12.x"
  s3_bucket                      = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket_prod.id
  s3_key                         = aws_s3_bucket_object.lambda_node_modules_prod.key
  source_code_hash               = data.archive_file.lambda_node_modules_prod.output_base64sha256
  timeout                        = 900

  tracing_config {
    mode = "PassThrough"
  }

}
```

and role

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec" {
  name    = "api_gateway_role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
  })
}
```

and then permissions

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "prod_api_gtw" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromApiGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.prod_options.function_name 
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.gateway_prod.execution_arn}/*/*"

}
```

After I deploy and try to invoke the url , I gget the following error

"integrationErrorMessage": "The IAM role configured on the integration or API Gateway doesn't have permissions to call the integration. Check the permissions and try again.",

I've been stuck with this for a while now. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Your error indicates API Gateway has assumed the role successfully, but the role lacks permission to invoke your lambda. Are you sure your last permissions block is correct? I would try granting it permission to invoke any lambda, and if that solves your problem, you can figure out how to correctly specify the lambda you need

Answer (score 3):

You may have to create a [Lambda permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission) to allow execution from an API Gateway resource:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.layout_editor_prod_options.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  # The /*/*/* part allows invocation from any stage, method and resource path
  # within API Gateway REST API.
  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.execution_arn}/*/*/*"
}
```

Also, for the Lambda `lambda_exec`, you don't need `apigateway.amazonaws.com` principal. The reason why we don't need this is that the [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) applies to the function and allows it to interact with other AWS services. In the other hand, this wont allow anything for the API Gateway, for that we need a [Lambda permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html).

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec" {
  name = "lambda_exec_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

In the other hand, I would add a policy to the Lambda execution role to be able to log to CloudWatch. This might be useful for further debugging:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_logging" {
  name        = "lambda_logging"
  path        = "/"
  description = "IAM policy for logging from a lambda"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_logs" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_logging.arn
}
```